# URISyntaxError when I called request.setURI(new URI(url)) while url is working fine on all browsers

Tags: android

I have a problem that when I call a url with many parameters for JSON response, then it shows an URISyntaxError but the same url is working fine on all browsers. I unable to understand what is going wrong?

```
The URL is: http://apibeta.highgearmedia.com/v1/vehicles/get-make-models.json?sort=mpg&filter=category&client-id=10030812&from=convertible&signature=QOwiWhG2T47KaQoyUztbag==
```

Code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(api_url));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,
                    "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while (true) {
                s = buf.readLine();
                if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
                    break;
                sb.append(s);

            }
            buf.close();
            ips.close();
            return sb.toString();
```

**Error:**

```
05-10 23:03:45.326: W/System.err(2227): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 161: http://apibeta.highgearmedia.com/v1/vehicles/get-make-models.json?sort=mpg&filter=category&client-id=10030812&from=convertible&signature=QOwiWhG2T47KaQoyUztbag==
05-10 23:03:45.326: W/System.err(2227):     at java.net.URI.validateQuery(URI.java:434)
05-10 23:03:45.326: W/System.err(2227):     at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:340)
05-10 23:03:45.335: W/System.err(2227):     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:72)
05-10 23:03:45.335: W/System.err(2227):     at com.TCC.android.ResearchList.getJsonSring(ResearchList.java:3892)
05-10 23:03:45.335: W/System.err(2227):     at com.TCC.android.ResearchList$67.run(ResearchList.java:4077)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution if your problem, a function that will remove all invalid characters from the url .Pass your url in this function and you will get a new url with encoded strings.

```
public static String convertURL(String str) {

    url = null;
    try{
    url = new String(str.trim().replace(" ", "%20").replace("&", "%26")
            .replace(",", "%2c").replace("(", "%28").replace(")", "%29")
            .replace("!", "%21").replace("=", "%3D").replace("<", "%3C")
            .replace(">", "%3E").replace("#", "%23").replace("$", "%24")
            .replace("'", "%27").replace("*", "%2A").replace("-", "%2D")
            .replace(".", "%2E").replace("/", "%2F").replace(":", "%3A")
            .replace(";", "%3B").replace("?", "%3F").replace("@", "%40")
            .replace("[", "%5B").replace("\\", "%5C").replace("]", "%5D")
            .replace("_", "%5F").replace("`", "%60").replace("{", "%7B")
            .replace("|", "%7C").replace("}", "%7D"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [java URI javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String%29), and to the underlying [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html) (§2.2 and 3.4), `=` is a reserved char and should be escaped (`%3D` for `=`)

By the way, you should use `android.net.URI`

Comment: Problem remains same, android.net.Uri is not supported with request.setURI(new Uri(api_url)); and %3D not works instead of =